# GeoIP API Setup for redirects

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, ip-geolocation

I have a [webpage](https://linestar.ca/contact-us/) for contact info with tabs along the top for 4 different locations.

When you click on a different location the contact info on the pages change and the URL updates to add #horizontalTabX (where X is Tab 1-4 accordingly). I am trying to use the GeoIP detection lookup plugin through WP but I am pretty inexperienced with PHP and APIs...

For testing purposes, I've tried to tell it to switch to the AB Tab when it sees my location as BC (where I am testing from).

The main parts I feel like I am messing up are where it says  if ($url = '/contact-us';()) and the switch case to add the #horizontalTab2 onto the contact-us/ URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am actively going through the documentation but I'm pretty lost.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'geoip_redirect', 5);
function geoip_redirect(){
if (is_admin())
    return;

// This condition prevents a redirect loop:
// Redirect only if the home page is called. Change this condition to the specific page or URL you need.
if ($url = '/contact-us';())
    return;

if (!function_exists('geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip'))
    return;

$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
$countryCode = $userInfo->mostSpecificSubdivision->isoCode;
switch ($countryCode) {
    case 'BC':
        $url = '/#horizontalTab2';
        break;
    case 'AB':
        $url = '/#horizontalTab2';
        break;
    default:
        $url = '';
}
if ($url) {
    wp_redirect(get_site_url(null, $url));
    exit;
}
}
});
```

Also, I would like the code to only execute on the contact page, Do I have to put anything on that page to make it execute or will it just always check if it's on that page?

Comment: I assumed anything with a ($) selector was jQuery, removed the tag sorry!

Comment: Nah, $ is just a character.  It can be used with anything javascript.  Unless you include the library and you see something like $() or $.blah, then you're not using jQuery (at least as the $ character).